# Moving a task from a backlog item to another

Tags: tfs

Hi I am new to TFS and I am in need to move a task , that is set to the next sprint , to the current sprint.

The folder structure in TFS is:

Current: `Sprint/Application/Application Active Sprint backlog`

Next: `Sprint/Application/Application Next Sprint backlog`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically?

Comment: You want to move a Task work item from one sprint to another one? Than you need to change the IterationPath of the Task, what can be done in WebAccess or TeamExplorer in VS for example. Another way is to use the API, which means you will need to programm a tool, but this only makes sense, if you want to make it automatically. If you need to change many items, define a query that shows them and open it in Excel, where you can do a bulk change.

Answer (score 3):

Edit Sprints should contain PBIs not Tasks. Assuming you meant PBIs (which contain Tasks) then here's a method for doing it in TFS 2013. Using the web interface, you drag it. This assumes you have:

1. The left sidebar list of sprints is visible.
2. You are looking at the future sprint that contains the PBI to be moved.
3. You have expanded the twisty for the current sprint.

To do the drag you click anywhere on the PBI, say the Title, and hold a moment. Move the mouse a bit and you'll see a ghostly rectangle representing that item. You can continue the drag over to the future sprint and release the right mouse button. The PBI and all of its tasks are moved to the iteration path of the future sprint.

You can also edit the PBI and each Task in it, but that's tedious and slows down the commitment meeting.

----edit----
This is described on Microsoft's site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191595.aspx